# Is it possible to use Bootstrap without it taking over the entire style?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there an easy way to use Bootstrap in an existing project?

Currently it adds styles for table,a etc. which messes up everything in the page.

I really love the modal window, some buttons, but I don't want to hunt bootstrap css all the time to switch items back to default styles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the "customize" feature on the bootstrap website to get only those features you want: [Twitter Bootstrap Download Page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html). Most of bootstrap's rules are explicit. You'll probably only want to leave out the reset rules which are implicit by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, I don't know why I didn't think of it my judgement must be clouded, do you know which items from that list needs to be ticked out in order to achieve what I want? I will probably exhaustively test different possibilities first thing in the morning, I am guessing I should tick out all Base CSS items

Comment: As I said, you'll probably want to remove the 'Normalize and Reset' option along with 'Body type and links', 'Code and pre', 'Headings, body, etc', 'Labels', 'Tables', and 'Forms'. That should take care of a majority of the invasive rules.

Comment: Updated to new customization link.

Comment: The current customization tool (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) does not provide these options. I unchecked everything and still got CSS file which messes up all elements.

Comment: But then you can't load bootstrap from a CDN anymore, you have to serve it from your own server...

Answer (score 9):

#### Bootstrap 3 // Less 1.4.0 edit:

After Bootstrap 3 and Less 1.4.0 has come out, bootstrap has started using the `:extend()` pseudo selector. This means that certain things will fail in the original code I've posted (you'll get some `.bscnt .bscnt form-horizontal` code which means you have to nest two divs inside eachother, which is just dumb). The easy way to fix this is to remove the first two lines from `bootstrap.less` (`@import variables.less` and `@import mixins.less`) and instead import these files outside of the `.bs-cnt` scope:

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

.bscnt {
    @import "bootstrap.less";
}
```

---

You can also download bootstrap from here: [Bootstrap source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/master) and then enter the "less" directory and add a file called "bootstrap-custom.less" where you'll enter the following content:

```
.bs-cnt {
    @import "bootstrap.less";
}
```

"bs-cnt" for BootStrap-CoNTainer. You can make it longer if you want, but remember that it'll be pasted in a lot of places in the compiled CSS, so it's to save space in the end file.

After you've done this, simple compile the bootstrap-custom.less file with your favourite less compiler ([SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) is pretty good if you're on Windows), and then you'll have a compiled bootstrap file that only works when you place a container element with the class of "bs-cnt".

```
<div class="bs-cnt">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-large">This button will be affected by bootstrap</button>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-danger">This however; Won't</button>
```

Comment: @sureshvv Can you check your compiled CSS file to see if everything has `.bs-cnt ` in front of it?

Comment: yes.. works great on chrome.. modal dialog does not pop up on firefox

Comment: @sureshvv Then it seems like firefox has a bug, but it doesn't seem likely. Can you upload your CSS file somewhere?

Comment: the site is http://vplan.in Try clicking on Register. Works on chrome but not on firefox. Used bootstrap3. Here is the css: http://vplan.in/misc_/IssueSite/bootstrap-vplan.css. It is minimized. Can put a readable version if that will help.

Comment: I found the problem. I was also using jquery.jqtransform.js which was choking firefox. Got rid of it.

Comment: nice technique, but `SimpLESS` simply not working at all! here is a `probably` fix for `simpLESS` issue!

Comment: @AriSusanto this is a rather old answer, and simpless stopped updating. There's a git repository of version 2 but AFAIC no binary. Personally I just use the command line lessc or my ide (phpstorm) for compiling now a days.

Answer (score 0):

I think the link in answered section is not already updated. Here is where you can customize your Bootstrap directly on GetBootstrap site:

[Customize and download - GetBootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Comment: But then you have to serve it on your own and cant load it from CDN

Answer (score 0):

**Using IFrame**

Just make one html document with bootstrap in it, have your bootstrap element that you want on that page, and use Iframe to get it on the other one..

**element_name.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Element</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Code for the actual element-->
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
iframe {
  border: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="element.html"></iframe>
<!--Other stuff on the page-->
</body>
</html>
```

The element in the element.html will be integrated in the index.html like it's own element, without even importing a single bootstrap stylesheet in the index.html and there is no need to make custom bootstraps, which can be tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You can tag the styles you want to not get overwritten by a special tag. Just put the [!important tag](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp). It can take a long time to paste it after every line of code but it'll be worth the time. Or you can use the bootstrap.css file instead of the bootstrap link and delete all the styles that are overriding your styles. You can download the bootstrap css file [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/)

Comment: If it's "worth the time" is debatable.